# Recommend a linux-based Site Search Engine?

Tags: search, search-engine

I need a site search engine to provide search for my members-only content. I've previously used [Fluid Dynamics Search Engine](http://www.xav.com/scripts/search/) but was wondering if there was anything that's been more recently updated.

Needs to index content via site crawling as opposed to filesystem crawling as all content is in a database. Also needs to run under FreeBSD / Linux.

Yes, sorry, not programming... but this is the best place to get great answers!

Comment: Just a note on what I ended up with... I went third-party search and signed up with http://www.indextank.com/ . I just have them handle it for me, and so far it's worked out great.

Answer (score 2):

[Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) from the [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) project might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1):

Another excellent one is [Xapian](http://xapian.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx should be pretty good as well:

[Sphinx Search](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/)