# Search Engine for website

Tags: c#, search-engine

I have website and I need to build search engine for it.

I do not know how to build that, I just wrote same query to get same important value.

but this does not give sense.

And thanks for any help.

Comment: It would be helpful to know some more specifics: What do you want your search engine to search for? Any text on a page? A specific item of data?

Comment: I want from search engine to search all my database, looking for any match.

Comment: From the "Related" sidebar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112248/building-a-web-search-engine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823634/best-search-engine-for-research-organisations-website http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523106/recommend-a-linux-based-site-search-engine and there are probably others.

Answer (score 2):

You could do one of two things:

1. Use a third party search engine such as [Google Site Search](http://www.google.com/sitesearch/). (You'll have to pay if you don't want google branding or ads)
2. Create your own. Maybe use [Lucene.net](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

It looks, you need to provide detailed `Search features` for your site. If so, In General you can do something like:

Provide `textboxes` and a `search` button. Create a `stroed procedure` which searches the database based on the textbox entries on `click` of the Search Button.

ref : [**Implementing search option**](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10136834/implementing-search-optio.aspx)

For detailed Search module implementation have a look at these samples:

- [**Static-Site Search Engine with
  ASP.NET/C#**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Searcharoo.aspx)
- [**Create a Site Search Engine in
  ASP.NET**](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4389/create-a-site-search-engine-in-aspnet/)